# passing parameters to initialize function using addDomListener

Tags: javascript, google-maps, initialization

I am using this code to load the google map.

```
function initialize() {

    // Map initialization

  }

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

My question is how can I send 2 parameters to this initialize function. For eg I would like to pass lat and lng.

Should I write,

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(lat,lng));
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use JS object:

```
initialize({'lat':1,'lng':2});

function initialize(coord) {
  alert(coord.lat);
}
```